# Why did this jQuery input selector require a filter workaround

Tags: jquery

The following line This does NOT work in my code in firefox/firebug (but works fine in JSFIDDLE), you will see below I have a work around, just wondering if anyone knows the internal reason  why?

```
var checkedVal = parseInt($('input[@name=' + uniqueNamePart + 'currDim]:checked').val(), 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/darrenshrwd/eqh2y/43/

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="blahcurrDim">One
<input type="radio" checked="" value="2" name="blahcurrDim">Two
<input type="radio" value="3" name="blahcurrDim">Three
<input type="radio" value="4" name="blahcurrDim">Four
```

​...

```
$('document').ready(

function() {

    var uniqueNamePart = "blah";

    var dimensionClick = function() {

        // This does NOT work in my code in firefox/firebug (but works fine in JSFIDDLE):
        var checkedVal = parseInt($('input[@name=' + uniqueNamePart + 'currDim]:checked').val(), 10);

        // This does work in both:
        //var myRadio = $('input[name=' + uniqueNamePart  + 'currDim]'),
        //    checkedVal = parseInt(myRadio.filter(':checked').val(), 10);        

        alert(checkedVal);

    };

    $('input[name=' + uniqueNamePart + 'currDim]:radio').click(dimensionClick);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) is malformed. An `@` character is not necessary:

```
var checkedVal
    = parseInt($('input[name=' + uniqueNamePart + 'currDim]:checked').val(), 10);
```

That code appears to work in your fiddle, but that's because the only `<input>` elements there are the radio buttons, so matching succeeds even if the invalid attribute selector is ignored.

Comment: Totally correct...that's what I get from copying that from another stackoverflow question.